# C# - StringDictionary - how to get keys and values using a single loop?

Tags: c#, collections

I am using `StringDictionary` collection to collect Key Value Pairs.

E.g.:

```
StringDictionary KeyValue = new StringDictionary();
KeyValue.Add("A", "Load");
KeyValue.Add("C", "Save");
```

During retrieval i have to form two `foreach` to get keys and Values (i.e)

```
foreach(string key in KeyValue.Values)
{
   ...
}

foreach(string key in KeyValue.Keys)
{
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to get the pair in single `foreach` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do a `foreach` loop on the dictionary, which will give you a [`DictionaryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.aspx) in each iteration. You can access the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.key.aspx) and [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.dictionaryentry.value.aspx) properties from that object.

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry value in KeyValue)
{
    // use value.Key and value.Value
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i needed exactly this answer, iterating through 'this.Context.Parameters' which returns DictionaryEntry Collection.

Comment: It's perfect with ListDictionary to use!

Comment: 10 Years later and a few things to note: 

Firstly, value.Key and value.Value come back as type object, which  for many use cases, a cast may be required even though the holding type is a `StringDictionary`

The examples in various answers achieve the cast implicitly or use a regular dictionary.

Secondly, the `StringDictionary` returns keys as lower-case whereas the regular `Dictionary` does not. The MS Doco states this but it can get overlooked.

Answer (score 14):

The StringDictionary can be iterated as `DictionaryEntry` items:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry item in KeyValue) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

I would suggest that you use the more recent `Dictionary<string,string>` class instead:

```
Dictionary<string, string> KeyValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();
KeyValue.Add("A", "Load");
KeyValue.Add("C", "Save");

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in KeyValue) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Sure .I will change the one to Dictionary<string,string>

Answer (score 4):

One should be enough:

```
foreach (string key in KeyValue.Keys)
{
  string value = KeyValue[key];

  // Process key/value pair here
}
```

Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: What you understand is right! Everybody's answer is working perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You have already many answers. But depending on what you want to do, you can use some LINQ.

Let's say you want to get a list of shortcuts that use the CTRL key. You can do something like:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("Ctrl+A", "Select all");
dict.Add("...", "...");

var ctrlShortcuts =
    dict
        .Where(x => x.Key.StartsWith("Ctrl+"))
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: The question was regarding use of StringDictionary, not Dictionary<string,string>.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry entry in KeyValue)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply enumerate over the dictionary itself. It should return a sequence of DictionaryEntry instances.

A better alternative is to use `Dictionary<string, string>`.